# Does EXCEPT execute faster than a JOIN when the table columns are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, except

To find all the changes between two databases, I am left joining the tables on the pk and using a date_modified field to choose the latest record. Will using `EXCEPT` increase performance since the tables have the same schema. I would like to rewrite it with an `EXCEPT`, but I'm not sure if the implementation for `EXCEPT` would out perform a `JOIN` in every case. Hopefully someone has a more technical explanation for when to use `EXCEPT`.

Comment: Do you need to compare all the columns?  Or, is there a single id column that can be used for the join?

Comment: Do recall that the database implementation of queries doesn't really map 1:1 to SQL keywords. It's more than possible that semantically equivalent constructs will translate to the same query plan.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to compare all the columns in order to update any changes. And I am using a primary key for the join.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way anyone can tell you that `EXCEPT` will always or never out-perform an equivalent `OUTER JOIN`. The optimizer will choose an appropriate execution plan regardless of how you write your intent.

That said, here is my guideline:

---

Use `EXCEPT` when *at least one* of the following is true:

1. The query is more readable (this will almost always be true).
2. Performance is improved.

And *BOTH* of the following are true:

1. The query produces semantically identical results, and you can demonstrate this through sufficient regression testing, including all edge cases.
2. Performance is not degraded (again, in all edge cases, as well as environmental changes such as clearing buffer pool, updating statistics, clearing plan cache, and restarting the service).

---

It is important to note that it can be a challenge to write an equivalent `EXCEPT` query as the `JOIN` becomes more complex and/or you are relying on duplicates in part of the columns but not others. Writing a `NOT EXISTS` equivalent, while slightly less readable than `EXCEPT` should be far more trivial to accomplish - and will often lead to a better plan (but note that I would never say `ALWAYS` or `NEVER`, except in the way I just did).

[In this blog post I demonstrate at least one case where `EXCEPT` is outperformed by both a properly constructed `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and of course by an equivalent `NOT EXISTS` variation](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: Other answer seems to be telling the OP that `EXCEPT` is *marginally faster*. And it's gone.

Comment: @njk yep, and I have linked to a counter-example. Again, if the OP is looking for `ALWAYS/NEVER`, he's not going to find it.

Comment: @njk I deleted my answer because it was too universal... in the tests I ran, `except` was marginally faster... but it wasn't accurate to say that it will usually be faster.  Aaron's answer is better because it addresses that there's other factors that need to be considered instead of just always trying to use `except`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand So in general, will an EXCEPT outperform a LEFT JOIN? I know there are several factors involved but I appreciate any input you may have. Thanks.

Comment: @JosephKiskaden you are not going to get an "in general" answer to that question, sorry. Way too many variables. You should test your ***specific*** scenario (you should be checking semantics anyway, so all that means is adding performance testing to those tests).

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . That is a great reference.  Any idea why the SQL Server compiler does *not* choose the best execution plan when there are multiple choices that return the same answer but have different performance?  I, for one, don't like to have to phrase a query in a particular way to get a particular plan.  This is even worse when you work with multiple databases.

Comment: Necro comment, but this is a very useful post.  A ***factor*** against the `EXCEPT` mechanism is that even if a MERGE can be used, the scalar operations would be processing all columns rather than just the identifier column(s).  This would be increasingly pronounced in a column store, as well as being increasingly relevant when the clustered index of the tables do not match.

Answer (score 5):

In the following example, the `LEFT JOIN` is faster than `EXCEPT` by **70%**
(PostgreSQL 9.4.3)

Example:

There are three tables. `suppliers`, `parts`, `shipments`.
We need to get all parts not supplied by any supplier in London.

Database(has indexes on all involved columns):

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
  id     bigint    primary key,
  city   character varying NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE parts (
  id     bigint    primary key,
  name   character varying NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE shipments (
  id          bigint primary key,
  supplier_id bigint NOT NULL,
  part_id     bigint NOT NULL
);
```

Records count:

```
db=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM suppliers;
  count
---------
 1281280
(1 row)

db=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parts;
  count
---------
 1280000
(1 row)

db=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shipments;
  count
---------
 1760161
(1 row)
```

Query using `EXCEPT`.

```
SELECT parts.*
  FROM parts

EXCEPT

SELECT parts.*
  FROM parts
  LEFT JOIN shipments
    ON (parts.id = shipments.part_id)
  LEFT JOIN suppliers
    ON (shipments.supplier_id = suppliers.id)
 WHERE suppliers.city = 'London'
;

-- Execution time: 3327.728 ms
```

Query using `LEFT JOIN` with table, returned by subquery.

```
SELECT parts.*
  FROM parts
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT parts.id
      FROM parts
      LEFT JOIN shipments
        ON (parts.id = shipments.part_id)
      LEFT JOIN suppliers
        ON (shipments.supplier_id = suppliers.id)
     WHERE suppliers.city = 'London'
  ) AS subquery_tbl
  ON (parts.id = subquery_tbl.id)
WHERE subquery_tbl.id IS NULL
;

-- Execution time: 1136.393 ms
```