# Left join vs EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure that calculates difference between a large table's last week's version vs this week's version (Current data).

Both `LEFT JOIN` and `EXCEPT` will eventually give same results. However I would like to know if there is a preferred approach to do so in terms of performance.

Comment: Have you profiled/benchmarked the two different approaches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does EXCEPT execute faster than a JOIN when the table columns are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693118/does-except-execute-faster-than-a-join-when-the-table-columns-are-the-same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` and `EXCEPT` do *not* produce the same results.

`EXCEPT` is set operator that eliminates duplicates.  `LEFT JOIN` is a type of join, that can actually produce duplicates.  It is not unusual in SQL that two different things produce the same result set for a given set of input data.

I would suggest that you use the one that best fits your use-case.  If both work, test which one is faster and use that.

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. I will apply both and identify the query performance.